# How RAM is used on CGI query?

Tags: apache2

The user sends a file via HTML form `<input type="file" ... />`
CGI script, installed on the server, receives the file and, say, writes it down to the disk. As simple as only possible.
As I understand, files, sent to the server via `POST`, are stored in the RAM on the Server, before they are written on the disk. (If I am not right - please, correct me).
The question is IF the file, that a user sends, weights **2GB** and the server (just for example) has only **1GB** of RAM on board? What will happen then?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer: the data is paged onto disk. So, there is no problems with CGI at sending vast data to server.
Thanks.

Comment: Like ram, disk space is not unlimited. What you need to do is limit the file upload size so that a guest wont upload hundreds of gigs of data in one go.